# errno in Multithread implementation

Tags: c++, c, errno

To use errno in multithread application this reference http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cerrno/errno/ indicates that it should be locally implemented in every thread. What does that mean?

Answer (score 4):

`errno` should be `thread-local`. In each `thread` value of this variable can be different.

> that it should be locally implemented in every thread

It's not your duty to implement `errno` as `thread_local` variable. It's work for compiler developers.

From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/errno)

> errno is a preprocessor macro used for error indication.
> **It expands to a thread-local modifiable lvalue of type int.**     (since C++11)

Simply in C++11 compilers this code should never assert

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cerrno>
#include <thread>
#include <cassert>

int g_errno = 0;

void thread_function()
{
   errno = E2BIG;
   g_errno = errno;
}

int main()
{
   errno = EINVAL;
   std::thread thread(thread_function);
   thread.join();
   assert(errno != g_errno && "not multithreaded");
}
```

Comment: My problem is how to do this? the usual procedure is to include the header #include <errno.h> and use directly errno. How to make it local?

Comment: tha above reference said that: **"Libraries that support multi-threading shall implement errno in a per-thread basis: With each thread having its own local errno"**. At the implementation level How does it look like?

Comment: @WildThing from C++ standard: A separate errno value shall be provided for each thread. "Libraries" means implementations really.

Comment: So i include errno.h and use errno in my class that implements multithreading without any other modification?

Comment: @WildThing exactly. It you use C++11 compiler, where this feature is implemented.

Comment: How can i check the version of my compiler?

Comment: @WildThing I don't know what compiler you use. For example you may try to execute code in my answer.

Comment: c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.0\include\c++\c++0x_warning.h:31: erreur : #error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.

Answer (score 3):

Historically, `errno` was a *common* variable of type `int` -- i.e. every module brought its own definition, and the linker was responsible for merging them. So programs simply stated `int errno;` globally and had a working definition.

This breaks down in multithreaded environments, because there is only a single variable. Thus, `errno.h` now needs to define something that is an *lvalue* `int`, and programs should not define their own `errno`.

The GNU C library for example defines something similar to

```
#define errno (*(__errno_location()))
```

where `__errno_location()` is an inline function that calculates the address of the thread-local `errno`.

All of this is of no concern to the application, except that it is an error to define your own `errno`.

Comment: Was it really a common variable? I thought it was an external variable defined in libc.

Comment: @Maxim, yes -- `extern int errno;` also works because that can also be used to refer to a common definition. Initializing with `int errno = 0;` fails to link, however.

Answer (score 0):

It means that each thread should have its own instance of the `errno` variable

The implementation can easily achieve this by using something like:

```
int __thread errno;
```

`__thread` being a gcc extension that ensures the variable is thread local (so one thread cannot overwrite another threads instance of the variable)

As a user of errno, you don't need to worry about this. You don't even need to worry that errno may have been pre-emptively changed by another thread.

Comment: Can you describe this procedure in more details please?